# export more than one data table in to a single excel file using excelHTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, ajax, datatable

I created 5 data tables in the same page and i want to allow the user to extract them in to the same excel file and specifically in the same sheet.

```
var exportAllButton = {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            excelStyles: [
                // Your global styles here
            ],
            autoFilter: true,
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':not(.not-export-col)',
            },
            className: 'btn btn-outline-dark',
            filename: 'AllTablesReport',
            text: 'Extract All',
            title: ''
        };

        let i = 0;
        var tableAsset = createDataTableFront(_$tableAsset, {
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'name'
                },
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'ticker'
                },
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'securityType'
                },
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'currency'
                },
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'entryDate'
                },
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'exitDate'
                },
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'entryPrice'
                },
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'exitPrice'
                },
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'quantity'
                },
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'strike'
                },
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'notional'
                },
            ],
            buttons: [exportAllButton],
            serverSide: false,
            excelName: 'Asset Report',
            responsive: null,
            ajax: ''
        });
        
        var summaryTableAsset = createDataTableFront(_$summaryTableAsset, {
            buttons: [exportAllButton],
            serverSide: false,
            excelName: 'Asset Report',
            responsive: null,
            ajax: ''
        });

        i = 0;
        var tableLiability = createDataTableFront(_$tableLiability, {
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'name'
                },
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'ticker'
                },
                {
                    targets: i++,
                    data: 'securityType'
                }
            ],
            buttons: [exportAllButton],
            excelName: 'Liability Report',
            responsive: null,
            serverSide: false,
            ajax: ''
        });
        var summaryTableLiability = createDataTableFront(_$summaryTableLiability, {
            buttons: [exportAllButton],
            excelName: 'Liability Report',
            responsive: null,
            serverSide: false,
            ajax : ''
        });
        var summaryTable = createDataTableFront(_$summaryTable, {
            buttons: [exportAllButton],
            excelName: 'Summary Table',
            responsive: null,
            serverSide: false,
            ajax : ''
        });
```

what should i modify on the "exportAllButton" so that if one of the buttons on any of these 5 tables is clicked i will extract the 5 tables in to single excel file .